Confirmation dialog sometimes disappears after the second it appears
I'm having some issues with deleting list cells in swiftui when using a confirmation dialog.
I expect that pressing the delete or swiping to delete would bring up the confirmation dialogue. However it does not work every time. Sometimes the confirmation appears and then immediately disappears and sometimes it works as intended. I don't have any errors or warnings in the code so I am not sure how best to trouble shoot this issue. Any help is appreciated.
This is the variables in the view struct body. I tried to consolidate the code I am having issues with.
struct ProjectDetailView: View {
    let project: Project
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    @State private var showingDeleteMirrorAlert = false
    @State private var mirrorToDelete: IndexSet?
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            List {
                DisclosureGroup("Mirrors") {
                    if project.mirrors.isEmpty {
                        ContentUnavailableView {
                            Image(systemName: "figure.strengthtraining.functional")
                            Text("This project has no mirrors.")
                        } description: {
                            Text("Add some if you want some.")
                        }
                    } else {
                        ForEach(project.mirrors) { mirror in
                            NavigationLink(destination: MirrorDetailView(mirrors: mirror)) {
                                MirrorCellView(mirror: mirror)
                            }
                        }
                        .onDelete { indexSet in
                            mirrorToDelete = indexSet
                            showingDeleteMirrorAlert = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .confirmationDialog(
                "Are you sure you want to delete this mirror?",
                isPresented: $showingDeleteMirrorAlert,
                titleVisibility: .visible
            ) {
                Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
                    if let indexSet = mirrorToDelete {
                        deleteMirror(indexSet: indexSet)
                    }
                    showingDeleteMirrorAlert = false
                    mirrorToDelete = nil
                }
                Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {
                    showingDeleteMirrorAlert = false
                    mirrorToDelete = nil
                }
            } message: {
                Text("This action cannot be undone.")
            }
        }
    }
    private func deleteMirror(indexSet: IndexSet) {
        for index in indexSet {
            let mirror = project.mirrors[index]
            context.delete(mirror)
        }
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error deleting mirror: \(error)")
        }
    }
}



This usually happens when there is some kind of state-related conflict.
In this case, it may be related to the confirmation dialog's .destructive role which removes the item from the list, as mentioned here.
Option 1:
One workaround is to set the button's role to .none:
Button("Delete", role: .none) {
    if let indexSet = mirrorToDelete {
        deleteMirror(indexSet: indexSet)
    }
    showingDeleteMirrorAlert = false
    mirrorToDelete = nil
}

This will cause the button to no longer be red and applying any tinting or other styling doesn't seem to work. If you want to keep the red button styling, maybe try the option below:
Option 2:
Another workaround is to keep your button with role .destructive, but switch from using .onDelete to a .swipeAction, as described here:
ForEach(project.mirrors) { mirror in
    NavigationLink(destination: MirrorDetailView(mirrors: mirror)) {
        MirrorCellView(mirror: mirror)
    }
}
.swipeActions {
    Button {
        showingDeleteMirrorAlert = true
        //deleteMirror(mirror.id)
    } label: {
        Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
    }
    .tint(.red)
}

By using .swipeAction, you will no longer have access to the index of the .onDelete, but you will gain direct access to the mirror object itself, which you'll be able to pass to deleteMirror.
You'll have to modify your deleteMirror function accordingly, to accept a mirror parameter, instead of index.

thanks! I will try those and see how it works. I did also find that moving the dialog outside the form appears to work properly but seems clunky to stack them for multiple lists.
